# Counts calculation for date range

Tags: sql

I have a table where I need to get number questions asked for each step and how many out of those questions were answered on that specific day. I need help with sql query

```
date               step              questions                 answers
01/01/2022         Bio-data          What is your name         John
01/01/2022         Bio-data          What is your dob          NULL
01/01/2022         Bio-data          What is your name         John
01/01/2022         Bio-data          What is your dob          NULL
01/02/2022         Registration      What is your name         John
01/02/2022         Registration      What is your address      Newyork
01/02/2022         Registration      What is your number       Null
01/02/2022         Registration      What is your name         John
01/02/2022         Registration      What is your address      Newyork
01/02/2022         Registration      What is your number       Null
```

Result set:

I need counts for date 01/01/2022 step Bio-data two unique questions were asked and just one was answered.

I need counts for date 01/02/2022 step Registration three unique questions were asked and just two were answered.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Comment: Microsoft T-sql

Answer (score 0):

```
create table QuestionAnswers (
   Date datetime,
   Step char(50),
   Question char(50),
   Answer char(50) NULL)

insert into QuestionAnswers values 
('2022-01-01',         'Bio-data',          'What is your name',         'John'),
('2022-01-01',         'Bio-data',          'What is your dob',          NULL),
('2022-01-01',         'Bio-data',          'What is your name',         'John'),
('2022-01-01',         'Bio-data',          'What is your dob',          NULL),
('2022-01-02',         'Registration',      'What is your name',         'John'),
('2022-01-02',         'Registration',      'What is your address',      'Newyork'),
('2022-01-02',         'Registration',      'What is your number',       NULL),
('2022-01-02',         'Registration',      'What is your name',         'John'),
('2022-01-02',         'Registration',      'What is your address',      'Newyork'),
('2022-01-02',         'Registration',      'What is your number',       NULL);


with
GrupedByAnswers as (
   select 
      [Date], 
      Step,
      Question,
      case when Answer is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end IsAnswered
   from QuestionAnswers)
select 
   [Date], Step, Question, IsAnswered, count(*) [Count]
from GrupedByAnswers
group by [Date], Step, Question, IsAnswered
```

| Date | Step | Question | IsAnswered | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Bio-data | What is your dob | No | 2 |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 | Bio-data | What is your name | Yes | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 00:00:00.000 | Registration | What is your address | Yes | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 00:00:00.000 | Registration | What is your name | Yes | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 00:00:00.000 | Registration | What is your number | No | 2 |

To understand better the problem it would be good to have expected result set as sample and not textual description.